# how to send a colon ":" via nircmd sendkeypres

Tags: sendkeys

I am using nircmd to simulate keypresses.

I want to send this text to the active window using nircmd sendkeypress function

```
"http://bing.com"
```

but the thing is the keycode for <kbd>:</kbd> always results in <kbd>;</kbd> due to using virtual keycode `0xBA`

So how do you simulate the <kbd>:</kbd> character or a <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> keypress using sendkeypress?

Answer (score 1):

Keycodes are language / keyboard layout specific

see here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/ and find your specific keycode. (use the Tester tool)

More information can be found here: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2010JulSep/att-0182/keyCode-spec.html

For example I have a german keyboard that means its key 190 which is "." and with shift resulting in ":"

to send the ":" I need to use "nircmd sendkeypress Shift+190"

this worked for me.